# Passing Config file Path as variable in function

Tags: python, configuration

I am reading a locally stored config file in my project folder. When the location for config file is hardcoded in `fileconfig.read('C:/FileConfig.ini')` there are no issues. But, when I pass the path variable of file in same function `fileconfig.read(path)` it gives empty value.

Please can anyone let me know how to provide file path in function `fileconfig.read(path)` function.

Python code:

```
def read_config_from_file(path):
    fileconfig = configparser.ConfigParser()
    # fileconfig.read('C:/FileConfig.ini') # works perfectly
    fileconfig.read(path)                  # Empty Value
    configfromFileDict = dict()
    for section in fileconfig.sections():
        # configfromFileDict[section] = {}
        for option in fileconfig.options(section):
            print(option, fileconfig.get(section, option))
            configfromFileDict[option] = fileconfig.get(section,option)

    return configfromFileDict

configurations = read_config_from_file('C:/FileConfig.ini')
```

Comment: Can you show how you are calling ```read_config_from_file```?

Comment: Added the call function

Comment: This should honestly be working.

Comment: yeah, add an import and an ini file and that code works. python 3.7.3